# Plus and minus button with EditText

Tags: android, kotlin, android-button

I have a functioning button with increment and decrement functioning correctly. but I have the need that I can also enter the value manually with an EdidText.

My code is the following:

Activity.tk

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    internal var minteger = 0
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val plus = findViewById<Button>(R.id.increase)
        val minus = findViewById<Button>(R.id.decrease)

        plus.setOnClickListener {

            increaseInteger(plus)
        }



        minus.setOnClickListener {

            decreaseInteger(minus)
        }
    }

    fun increaseInteger(view: View) {
        minteger += 1
        display(minteger)

    }

    fun decreaseInteger(view: View) {
        minteger -= 1
        display(minteger)
    }

    private fun display(number: Int) {
        val displayInteger = findViewById<View>(
                R.id.integer_number) as TextView
        displayInteger.text = "" + number
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/decrease"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/integer_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="70sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/increase"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="+" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I have changed the TextView with an EditText (`@+id/integer_number`)

But when I enter a value that is not saved, I can not find a way to make the value entered in the EdidText saved so that I can increase or decrease it.

I will appreciate any suggestion to be able to operate my button.

[image: buton]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your xml change to the `EditText`:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/integer_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="70sp" />
```

I added the attribute:

```
android:inputType="number"
```

so only digits are allowed.
In your `MainActivity` class add this import:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

so you can access all the items of the xml without the need of `findViewById()`.
Now you don't need to save the value of the `EditText` anywhere because you can get it anytime by:

```
integer_number.text.toString().toInt()
```

so the variable `minteger` is no longer needed.
Change the activity's code to this:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        increase.setOnClickListener { increaseInteger() }
        decrease.setOnClickListener { decreaseInteger() }
    }

    fun increaseInteger() {
        display(integer_number.text.toString().toInt() + 1)
    }

    fun decreaseInteger() {
        display(integer_number.text.toString().toInt() - 1)
    }

    private fun display(number: Int) {
        integer_number.setText("$number")
    }
}
```

I made other simplifications too.
You don't need any arguments for the functions `increaseInteger()` and `decreaseInteger()`.
There is a limitation on the maximum and minimum integer values. 
So if you want to be on the safe side you must also use a `try/catch` block inside `increaseInteger()` and `decreaseInteger()` to avoid exceptions.